# Google App Engine: Change thousands of entities at once?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, task-queue

Basically, I would like to update about 10,000 entities at once — adding a new property and value to each entity.

Given this class:

```
Post(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

I would like to run some sort of operation that would create this new `created_date_string` property in my existing `Post` entities and occupying the field with a string version of the date.

```
Post(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    created_date_string = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

How do I handle this?

My best guess is to use task queues to update each entity; we would be queueing 10,000 tasks. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in a single task where that task iterates over the entities to update them.  You'll want to batch your gets and puts to make it more efficient.  Tasks run for up to 10 minutes, and I bet this would take less than a minute.

Are you sure you need this new property?  You could do this:

```
Post(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

    @property
    def created_date_string(self):
        return str(self.created_date)
```

UPDATE:

I should have explained the confusing terminology.  There are two completely different uses of "property" here.  The property in my answer is specific to Python and has nothing to do with GAE.  The `@property` of Python makes a function look like a variable so can do `x.created_date_string` instead of `x.created_date_string()`

Instead of what I wrote above, you could do:

```
Post(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

    def created_date_string(self):
        return str(self.created_date)
```

It is basically the exact same thing.

The Python property is different from a GAE computed property, which is an actual property in the datastore.  You could use that as well, but why store redundant data if you don't need to.

Comment: Is this similar to the concept of a computed property? Will this compute every time this property is accessed, and will it cost to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the **String** version of **created_date** property in **created_date_string**. There are two use cases I can think of for doing this.

1. Using **created_date_string** on server only: If you are using this property on server side only, then there is no need to store it as it becomes redundant, you can calculate it via instance methods for model class.
2. Send **created_date_string** in API response: If you are sending this property via API and using it on client side(web/app etc.). Then the best option is to use the **ComputedProperty** of Google App Engine as shown below

   created_date_string = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: str(self.created_date))

   this way your **created_date_string** property will always be consistent with **created_date** and will automatically be created and stored in DataStore.

You can find more info on ComputedProperty [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#computed)

Comping back to your original question about how to update 10,000 entities. As it a one job task I would recommend using **deffered**. It also uses task queue but is comparatively easy to use. As mentioned in the definition:

*The deferred library lets you bypass all the work of setting up dedicated task handlers and serializing and deserializing your parameters by exposing a simple function deferred.defer()*

You can find the documentation [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred). The example given itself is synonymous to what you are asking i.e. to run batch updates.

Here is how I would do it.

1. Write a dedicated handler(example: **/runbatchupdate**) that will start your update using deffered
2. Hit the handler from outside or make an entry in your cron.yaml to run this handler.

If you need a sample code then comment below and I will write a sample handler for you. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for offering to write the sample code. I would appreciate learning from an example!